# How to apply themes on Telegram on a Mac?

Tags: telegram

I am trying to apply themes in Telegram on Mac OS & following [this guide](https://draculatheme.com/telegram/) but it's not working.

These are the steps I am following -

### Activating theme

1. In Telegram Desktop, go to `setting` and under the `Chat background` section click on `Choose from file`.
2. Select the `colors.tdesktop-theme` file you just downloaded.
3. Click `Keep Changes` to apply the theme.

It doesn't show the 2nd step. The file is de-selected from the `Choose from file` popup.

My version is 5.2.2 (170992) Stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to apply theme for to a [Swift version of Telegram](https://macos.telegram.org/), which is a native app created specifically for macOS.

However [that theme](https://draculatheme.com/telegram) is made for [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org), a cross-platform app for Windows, Linux and macOS (yes, macOS has 2 official clients, you can read about their differences [here](https://telegram.org/faq#q-why-do-you-have-two-apps-in-the-mac-app-store))

Comment: I knew about the 2 apps, thanks for clarifying but can I apply Theme for Swift version or it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @deadcoder0904 I'm not sure that exactly this theme exists for macOS (well, making themes for macOS client is pain in the ...)

Comment: sarcasm. electron makes it easy to apply themes & all :)